# Is there a way to enlarge the InDesign interface elements?

Tags: adobe-indesign, interface-design

I'm using inDesign 9.2 since yesterday and I find the interface elements incredibly small. For example when selecting the TEXT tool and looking at the options on top bar (fonts, alignment, etc), it takes some effort to, say, increase font size by clicking on the up arrow in font size section:

[image: InDesign interface]

Is there any way to make it look a little bit less ant-like and make it easier to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only way to make the user Interface larger is to reduce the resolution of your monitor or get a larger monitor.

Although at times I think about investing in these...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I was at an InDesign User's Group meeting last night at a local university, and this question came up. Apparently there isn't a way to increase the GUI icon sizes (at least according to the experts presenting last night).

If enough of us complain to Adobe, maybe they'll change that in the future?

Comment: It *has* been asked for years on end... First, for the older InDesign's by those with less acute vision (a group I find myself sliding towards with each year), currently by those with spanking new high-rez monitors. But feel free to post [an official Feature Request](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&loc=en) at Adobe's.

Comment: I'm one of those older designers. It's been a blast trying to design 16px icons, let me tell you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows, increase font size to 125% or more in
**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display**. Log off and log in again. InDesign's interface will have large fonts.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac you can scale up (or down) your whole screen content via "System Preferences > Displays > Resolution: Scaled > Larger Text.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's still no option to change the size of the menus in Indesign.

**But you can still have some control on the icon size in your System's preferences.**

- **You can always change the display resolution** to increase the size of what you see on it. That means you can use a lower resolution and
  the icons and everything will look a bit bigger. That's not a fancy
  way to do this but sometimes it's necessary. You can usually have a shortcut for this in the menu bar on Mac.
- **Another option is to go in the Accessibility Preferences on Mac** (Windows certainly have some good options for this too). It's
  possible to keybind some special zoom that you can use when you need
  it. Of course this may affect slightly your productivity but not
  seeing the texts and icons also affect it!
  In the Accessibility Panel, you can also change the size of the cursor and the contrast.